# jQuery selectors: multiselect vs select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Is it possible, via jQuery, to select a multiselect to a select, differently?

The issue I'm having is that I have a general js called that does something to an id. However on some pages it has a different purpose.

Therefore I would like about to recognize the difference.

```
$("select#categories[multiselect]").doOneThing; //multiselect
$("select#categories").doAnotherThing; //normal single select
```

Possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct attribute name for a `<select>` element with multiple selectable options is *multiple*.  You can use the "has attribute" selector to select elements with the multiple attribute, and combine it with *:not()* to select elements that only allow a single selection.

Therefore, your jQuery selector should be:

```
$("select#categories[multiple]")  // <select> with multiple 
$("select#categories:not([multiple])")  // <select> with single only
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this (XHTML):

```
<select id="categories" size="3" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

You could create a selector, that checks for the `multiple`-attribute. Try something like this:

```
$('select#categories[multiple="multiple"]').doOneThing();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to apply to all multiple selects on the page just use this:

`$('select[multiple]')`